# Having trouble with conditional html "programming"

Tags: javascript, html

Old onetime mainframe programmer. 
Trying to conditionally display or not display html.
Searched and tried numerous suggestions. No luck. Would greatly appreciate help.
Latest test attempt:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>July 27 - Lang Bay </title>
</head>
<script language="javascript">
    var x = 0;
    function hola(x) {
        if(x == 0) {           
          document.getElementById("showpage").style.visibility="hidden";
        }
    }
</script>
<body>
<div id="showpage">
    <p><font size=+1>July 27 - Lang Bay </font>
    <br><TABLE>
    <TR>
    <TD><br><a href="../../jpg/2009/090727_052p.jpg"><img SRC="../../jpg/2009/090727_052ptn.jpg"><br>B.C., Lang Bay<br>Afternoon on the beach </a>
    <TD><br><a href="../../jpg/2009/090727_053p.jpg"><img SRC="../../jpg/2009/090727_053ptn.jpg"><br>B.C., Lang Bay<br>Heather McCutcheon, Sydney </a>
</div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You have the function defined and everything good, but you didn't call (run) the function.

Comment: Another important thing - you need to make sure that you call the function **after** the page was completely loaded (otherwise the element with the id `showpage` isn't there yet, and you can't `document.getElementById` an element that doesn't exists yet).

Answer (score 1):

The language attribute for script elements was deprecated in [HTML 4 (1999)](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/) and has been removed in later versions. Don't use it.

In your code there is:

```
var x = 0;
function hola(x) {
  if (x == 0) {           
    document.getElementById("showpage").style.visibility="hidden";
  }
}
```

When you provide a parameter in the formal parameter list of a function declaration (i.e. the *x* in `function hola(x){...}` then it's equivalent to declaring the variable inside the function body, so *x* in the function references that local *x*, not the global one. You can either remove *x* from the parameter list, or pass it in the call, e.g.

```
function hola() {
  // use global x
}
```

or

```
function hola(x) {
  // use local x
}

// pass value of global x in the call
hola(x);
```

Since you haven't shown how *hola* is called, the simplest fix is the second.

As the comments have said, you need to call the function after the elements have loaded. Use *window.onload* for that:

```
window.onload = function() {
  hola(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: wait for the window to load, then call `hola`. (In javascript, you need to call functions to invoke the code inside them).

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  hola(0);
});
```

Additionally, you need to pass `0` into `hola`, because the `x` parameter declared in `hola` overrides the global variable `x`.